# with_options not working in RoR3 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

Can someone please explain to me why it seems to ignore the with_options block in this code?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name,:user_type,:policy_num,:address,:city,:state,:zip,:phone,:fax,:email,
                :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password
has_many :policies
has_many :dealer_forms

before_save {|user| user.email = email.downcase}
before_save :create_remember_token

ZIP_REGEX = /^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
COMPLEX_PHONE_REGEX = /^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/

validates :name, presence: true, length:{in:4..50}
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},format:{with:EMAIL_REGEX}
validates :password, length:{in:6..20}, if: :password
validates :password_confirmation, presence:true, if: :password
validates :user_type, presence: true, inclusion: {in: %w(Dealer Producer System)}

# Validate True User items skip admin users #
with_options :unless => :is_system_user? do |u|
  u.validates :policy_num, presence: true
  u.validates :address, presence: true
  u.validates :city, presence: true
  u.validates :state, presence: true, length:{is: 2} 
  u.validates :zip, presence: true, format:{with:ZIP_REGEX,message: "Not a valid Zip Code"}
  u.validates :phone, allow_blank: true, format:{with:COMPLEX_PHONE_REGEX}
  u.validates :fax, allow_blank: true, format:{with:COMPLEX_PHONE_REGEX}
end

private
  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
  def is_system_user?
    user_type == "System" ? true : false
  end
end
```

I have tried the following:

```
with_options unless: :is_system_user?
with_options unless: Proc.new{|user| user.user_type == "System"}
with_options unless:"user_type = 'System'"
with_options if: "user_type != 'System'"
```

but for some reason when I try and create a user in the console it still runs the validations inside the block.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but `user_type == "System" ? true : false` is redundant. Just `user_type == "System"` is exactly the same

Comment: @Chowlett I was just typing almost that exact sentence.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately as you notated not really where the issue is

Comment: Problem is solved but on a similar note does reload! in the console not reload model validations? It seems when I was in the console and making changes they did not update with reload!

Comment: `reload!` means to discard any local changes and fetch the database version. Validation only occurs at `save` or `update` time. Please consider answering your own question (if you think it would be helpful to others) or closing it.

Comment: I would answer my own question but I haven't been on stackoverflow long enough. How can I close it?

Comment: @engineersmnky would appreciate it if you uploaded your answer. What do you need to answer? more points? or just to wait a while before posting?

Comment: @jay. I need more points to answer my question. The answer was simple though the code was right but to test model behaviors in irb you must restart irb when you make changes like this or reload the file into irb using load(path/to/file)